# How can I translate my programmatic WCF configuration into app.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5, wcf-binding

I have an self hosted WCF server with hard coded configurations. the server worked fine until I tried to implement some new configurations functionality (changed ports,  added ssl) the new config setting did not work (urrr.... ) and I find it hard to locate where are the problems in my code.

instead of digging inside the code that declares the WCF object, I thought about different approach:

Is there any way to dump-to-file those hard coded WCF configuration (the entire  ) into app.config like text file after all configurations are loaded? this will enable me to have a easy global view of the entire settings ..

mmm .. .by the way, does anyone know a way that will do the translation to the opposite direction? config to code.

Any advice will be welcomed!

ofer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find an automatic way to dump your c#/vb code somewhere and have your configuration converted to the config file xml schema (and vice-versa), however if you ask my personal opinion, if you don't have a strong reason to hard-code your configuration in your code (even if you do so, I would rethink that), you should move the wcf configuration out from your code. Configuration is not responsibility of the code. It is configuration, meaning that if you need to change the "configuration", you don't need a new build.

In your code, you should just concentrate in the service consumption logic, leaving the configuration to the back-end engine take care of it. Remember that sometimes you may need adjust some settings, like service throttling, max/min buffer size, MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota, etc. If hard-coded, means a new deployment. If in a config file or other repository, means a simple configuration change.

If you have all your configuration in a config file, when you move your code from environment to environment (Dev, DIT, QA, UAT, Pre-Prod, Production), you can have different settings between environments, if required (because the port number you used is already in use or is blocked in the firewall). The release management team will just configure it properly in the config file.

If you want more control over your service configuration, you could consider creating a factory service for your services, where will get all your configuration from a centralized place (database, xml file, etc), and you will configure your code on-the-fly.

I hope it helps...